# How to normalize rewrite rules that always decrease the input's size?

Tags: agda

Mind the following datatype:

```
data AB : Set where
  A : AB -> AB
  B : AB -> AB
  C : AB

rwt : AB -> AB
rwt (B (A ab)) = rwt ab
rwt (A ab)     = A (rwt ab)
rwt (B ab)     = B (rwt ab)
rwt C          = C

ab : AB
ab = rwt (rwt (B (B (A (A (A (A (B (B (A (B C)))))))))))
```

Here, `rwt` is meant to replace all occurrences of `B (A x)` by `x`. The way it is written, though, doesn't guarantee the result is in normal form, which can be seen by the fact we needed two applications of `rwt` to get to `A (A (B (B x)))`, which can't be further rewritten.

**Is there any way to write `reduce : AB -> AB` in Agda that will return the same result as if we called `rewrite` repeatedly until no `B (A x)` is left? And, can we also get a proof of that (perhaps `reduce : (input : AB) -> Σ AB (λ output . is-reduction-of input && is-in-nf output`)?**

### An attempt:

The program below will always return the normal form of `ab`:

```
reduce : AB -> ℕ -> AB
reduce (A ab) (suc n) = reduce ab n
reduce (A ab) zero    = A (reduce ab zero)
reduce (B ab) n       = reduce ab (suc n)
reduce C      (suc n) = B (reduce C n)
reduce C      zero    = C
```

But how do we prove it actually returns a term without "redexes", and that it is equivalent to `rwt (rwt (rwt ... ab))`? I'm asking because I expect there to be popular techniques to deal with that situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define rewriting inductively, then say that a normal term is not rewritable to anything. Then, prove that `reduce` is sound and returns normal forms.

```
open import Data.Empty
open import Data.Nat
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Relation.Nullary

data AB : Set where
  A : AB -> AB
  B : AB -> AB
  C : AB

-- 1-step rewrite
infix 3 _~>_
data _~>_ : AB → AB → Set where
  BA : ∀ {x} → B (A x) ~> x
  A  : ∀ {x y} → x ~> y → A x ~> A y
  B  : ∀ {x y} → x ~> y → B x ~> B y

-- reflexive-transitive closure
infixr 5 _◅_
data Star {A : Set}(R : A → A → Set) : A → A → Set where
  ε   : ∀ {x} → Star R x x
  _◅_ : ∀ {x y z} → R x y → Star R y z → Star R x z

-- n-step rewrite
infix 3 _~>*_ 
_~>*_ : AB → AB → Set
_~>*_ = Star _~>_

normal : AB → Set
normal ab = ∀ {ab'} → ¬ (ab ~> ab')

-- TODO
reduceSound  : ∀ ab → ab ~>* reduce ab 0
reduceNormal : ∀ ab → normal (reduce ab 0)
```

You will need to generalize `reduceSound` and `reduceNormal` for cases other than `0`. Otherwise, both are provable by direct induction, so I don't think it could be made easier by any particular technique.

Comment: Solution spoiler [here](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/9a5bfb91c266b96fe394cdea6d7458f0).

Comment: Thanks! I love the idea of representing rewriting inductively, makes perfect sense. But I'm not familiar with Star. Any recommended resource?

Comment: @MaiaVictor I pasted here the `Star` definition. The only thing we need are the constructors. It's just for extending ~> to multi-step.